# New Laravel vhost downloads php instead of executing, while the existing vhost works

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have an existing Laravel 5.5 project which works on Mac with built-in apache and has a virtual host.

Recently, I had to maintain a new Laravel project, which was already been developed in progress, and I did to it with the same steps that I did to the existing project.

But, the new project can just download the index.php file under public.

I've searched the relevant questions and tried most of the solutions(like [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)), however, none of them worked.

Does anybody know about this strange situation?

Comment: I'm using Laragon 5.0. and facing the same issue, as soon as I run something.test, it downloads some file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the apache didn't get the index file format correctly, so once I ran the virtual host, it would only download the php file.

After I add "index.php" in the DirectoryIndex statement in httpd.conf, the problem was perfectly solved.